# Console utility to know how disk space is distributed?

Tags: disk-usage

Console utility to know how disk space is distributed.

Something like this:

[image: Scanner screenshot]

But with console interface in Linux?

Comment: OK, this is confusing. Your screenshot is from windows, but the question is tagged with "linux". What are you looking for?

Comment: I'm more confused by what the Russian script in the picture is really saying

Comment: I think I may be more confused as to why people upvote the question, when it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could look at the [ncdu utility](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) or [kdirstat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/).

```
The typical ncdu output looks like:

ncdu 1.7 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                         
--- /data ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  163.3GiB [##########] /docimages                                                                                  
   84.4GiB [#####     ] /data
   82.0GiB [#####     ] /sldata
   56.2GiB [###       ] /prt
   40.1GiB [##        ] /slisam
   30.8GiB [#         ] /isam
   18.3GiB [#         ] /mail
   10.2GiB [          ] /export
    3.9GiB [          ] /edi   
    1.7GiB [          ] /io     
    1.2GiB [          ] /dmt
  896.7MiB [          ] /src
  821.5MiB [          ] /upload
  691.1MiB [          ] /client
  686.8MiB [          ] /cocoon
  542.5MiB [          ] /hist
  358.1MiB [          ] /savsrc
  228.9MiB [          ] /help
  108.1MiB [          ] /savbin
  101.2MiB [          ] /dm
   40.7MiB [          ] /download
```

Also see: https://serverfault.com/questions/301423/how-can-i-determine-what-is-taking-up-so-much-space

Answer (score 3):

While it's not pretty, I suggest `du -hs /*`. That will show all of the files and directories in `/` and how large they are.  Or `/* /*/*` if you want the first two levels of directories, etc.  Or `du -h /` if you want EVERY subdirectory rather that top-level totals.

Either way, this will take a bit of grinding to go through all the directories and add all the files up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to draw graphs in ASCII, but you could try the `df` command.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_buildboxel6-lv_root
                       28G   14G   13G  52% /
tmpfs                 939M   76K  939M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1             485M   55M  405M  12% /boot
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `di`:

```
$ di
Filesystem         Mount               Size     Used    Avail %Used fs Type
/dev/sda1          /                  22.3G    13.1G     9.2G  59%  jfs    
udev               /dev              996.4M   200.0K   996.2M   0%  tmpfs  
tmpfs              /dev/shm         1001.6M       0   1001.6M   0%  tmpfs  
/dev/sda2          /home              50.2G    32.2G    17.9G  64%  jfs
```

Comment: `-bash: di: command not found`. It's not in any of my usual Enterprise Linux repositories either. Where did you find it?

Comment: `apt-get install di`. From the [webpage](http://www.gentoo.com/di), it seems to be available for a range of operating systems: FreeBSD, Arch, Debian, CRUX, Gentoo, Mint, Ubuntu ...

Comment: Gentoo. Hahaha. That's why I never heard of it. :)

Answer (score -2):

I think you're after something in the shape of Firelight, Disk Usage Analyser or similar ones...

http://www.howtogeek.com/185173/4-ways-to-free-up-disk-space-on-linux/